Unwanted logs generated in datadog of python application
I am getting below error logs whenever my service hit.
"[2024-05-13 05:58:21 +0000] [67] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 67"
"[2024-05-13 05:58:21 +0000] [1] [INFO] Using worker: sync"
"[2024-05-13 05:58:21 +0000] [1] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:5000,http://0.0.0.0:8080 (1)"
"[2024-05-13 05:58:21 +0000] [1] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 21.2.0"
"[2024-05-13 05:58:21 +0000] [67] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 67)"
"[2024-05-13 05:58:21 +0000] [1] [INFO] Shutting down: Master"
"[2024-05-13 05:58:21 +0000] [1] [INFO] Handling signal: term"

How To disable above messages?
I have tried below code to filter out the error logs.
    import logging
    import re

    class CustomFilter(logging.Filter):
        def __init__(self, blocked_patterns):
            super().__init__()
            self.blocked_patterns = blocked_patterns

        def filter(self, record):
            # Check if the log message matches any of the blocked patterns
            for pattern in self.blocked_patterns:
                if re.match(pattern, record.getMessage()):
                    # If a blocked pattern is found, return False to filter out the log record
                     return False
            # If no blocked pattern matches, allow the log record to pass through
            return True

    # Configure logging
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)

    # Define the list of patterns to be blocked
    blocked_patterns = [
        r".*\[INFO\] Booting worker with pid: \d+",
        r".*\[INFO\] Using worker: .*",
        r".*\[INFO\] Listening at: http://0\.0\.0\.0:5000,http://0\.0\.0\.0:8080 \(1\)",
        r".*\[INFO\] Starting gunicorn \d+\.\d+\.\d+",
        r".*\[INFO\] Worker exiting \(pid: \d+\)",
        r".*\[INFO\] Shutting down: Master",
        r".*\[INFO\] Handling signal: term",
        r".*http://metadata\.google\.internal/computeMetadata/.*"
    ]

    # Create a logger
    logger = logging.getLogger()

    # Add the custom filter to the logger
    logger.addFilter(CustomFilter(blocked_patterns))

However, the error logs were not filtered out.

The message won't contain INFO – that's part of the message formatting. Also, if you're doing this configuration in your app's configuration, it likely won't affect Gunicorn's logs (which is what you're trying to filter out).

See https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/latest/settings.html#logging for some gunicorn logging configuration settings.
